# How do I make an anchor in a scrolling list extend to its children's width?

Tags: html, css

I've set this up here: http://jsfiddle.net/9F6CF/

Basically, I have a list with anchors inside the LIs.  The UL has a defined width and an automatic overflow, so if the text in the anchors extends wider than the width of the UL, it will scroll horizontally.

Every element is set to have a block level display, however the anchors only extend to the defined width of the UL as opposed to (what I would like to happen) extending to contain the bounds of its text.  Thus, I lose any background or border style that I would have applied to the LIs or anchors in the overflow area.

Is there a way I can get the anchors to wrap around the full width of their children without setting an explicit width on all the anchors?

Markup

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">0000000436274637264378234</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.menu li {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this dinamicaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.menu li {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}

.menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
 /* display: block; */
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9F6CF/1/)

Comment: Wild, thank you. I need to ask, why do I need to clear and then float the LI?

Comment: It's needed to push succeeding floated `li`'s to a new line.